# Contents of Windows Form do not display

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have just started coding a simple windows form, but when I compile it the buttons/textboxes does not display.

Only a blank window pops up.

Comment: Show the code in InitializeComponent function.

Comment: @Pankaj InitializeComponent();
   //
   //TODO: Add the constructor code here
   //

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is nothing in your InitializeComponent function.
Add this code in the function and you should see a button with "Connect" written on it.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   System.Windows.Forms.Button ConnectBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
   ConnectBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
   ConnectBtn.Name = "ConnectBtn";
   ConnectBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
   ConnectBtn.Text = "Connect";

   this.Controls.Add(ConnectBtn);
}
```